# Insight to np.linalg.lstsq and np.linalg.pinv limitations and failures during multiprocessing?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I am seeking insight into a vexing problem I have encountered using numpy in a multiprocessing environment.  Initially, some weeks ago, "things did not work" at all and as a result of guidance from this site, the problem was traced to numpy needing to be recompiled to allow multiprocessing.  This was done and appears at first blush to be functional EXCEPT that now there are limits on the problem size that I can attack.

When numpy was used "as downloaded as binary distribution" in single processor mode, I could solve large problems using linalg.pinv and linalg.svd without complaint (except for throughput).  Now, relatively small problems fail.  Specifically, when linalg.lstsq is called (which appears to invoke svd and/or pinv) the code expends the cpu effort (as shown by process monitor) but the code never executes the next statement after the linalg call.  No exception is raised, no error indication given, no results generated; it just bails and the process that contains the call is deemed done and that is that.

These matrices are not that large: 8 x 4096 will solve and create results in a timely manner.  8 x 8192 fails with no error indication, no exception raised and no results are produced.  The single process version of numpy solved 12 x 50,000 without issue.  My platform is a 12-core Mac running most-recent OS X (10.11.6) with 64GB of physical ram.  Minimal memory pressure is put on the machine during these runs; there is plenty of headroom on space.  Python is 2.7.11 under anaconda, numpy was recompiled for multiprocessing using gcc.

I am running out of places to look; I have not found a numpy control  that address this issue.  Does anyone have any pointers as to where I should concentrate my search for a resolution?

This is a show-stopper for me and I have to assume that the underlying cause is simple, but perhaps not obvious.  I am rather new to python, so I would appreciate any insight fellow over-flowers may have.

Comment: This might be closed for lack of a `mcve`: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  If it's impossible to provide that, SO might be wrong place to ask this.

Comment: If you can add an MCVE, I can add a bounty.